# Qt video examples does not work

Tags: qt, video

I have Qt 2010.02.01, Windows 7.

In Exampels directory there are two video player examples:
`/multimedia/videographicsitem`, `/multimedia/videowidget`
But both of them does not work. They can show pictures (`.jpg`), but they cant open any `.avi` file (when open avi file, they just do nothing)...
(I have all codecs installed)

Is there any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

check qt phonon... creating simple video player is like 5 lines of code